# Qt Creator is missing some modules

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I have Qt Creator installed on a windows 10 machine. There are some essential modules I need to use (Qt charts, TableModel) but they aren't available in creator. How can I install them ?

Comment: QtCreator has nothing to do with Qt. What Qt version did you install? If Qt6 then some modules are not yet available - downgrade to 5.15.2

Comment: @chehrlic QtCreator is part of Qt. See: [development tools](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools).

Comment: No, QtCreator is not *part of* Qt. It's just an IDE made with Qt which was designed to properly work with Qt.

Comment: @chehrlic It's a project developed by The Qt Company which resides in [Qt's git repository](https://code.qt.io/cgit/) - so it's part of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

because QtCharts is no under LGPL licence isn't install by qt installer as default module. if yo want add Qt Chart widget as a designer item,you can use promotion("promote to") according to official documents :
[Qt Document](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)